# Force pasted values to obey data validation rules

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a (simplified example) matrix consisting of inputs and alarms. Each action (X) should have an input and an alarm i.e. no actions should be inserted in column E or row 6.

[image]

I used data validation to implement this and it works.

[image]

However if I paste data to these cells they do not follow the validation rules. I inserted this VBA code to prevent this (extracted from www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip98.htm):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("ValidationRange")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
        " It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
'   Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

However, this code also prevents values from being pasted into cells even when they do not break validation rules e.g. if I paste an X to input a;alarm 1, I get an error message. Is there any way to prevent values from being pasted only when they break validation rules?

Edit:

I have altered the code to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Range("D4:H8").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=OR(ISBLANK(D4),AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C4)),NOT(ISBLANK(D$3))))"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Stop"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Actions Must Have Input and Output"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

Me.CircleInvalid

Count = 0
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, Range("D4:H8")) Is Nothing Then Count = Count + 1
Next

If Count > 0 Then
MsgBox "Actions Must Have Input and Output"
End If

End Sub
```

This now circles invalid cells and produces a msg box if one is found. This is done based on the fact that the invalid circle is a shape. I can get the code to work by searching the whole sheet but I am trying to narrow the search to a specified range. However I get the error "1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error" due to shp.TopLeftCell. Any ideas?

Comment: There are too many answers needed to solve this. J-Walk's code was a specific example of preventing cells being pasted into a data validated range. Do you re-instate the validation and check for invalid entries through the entire range; define the copied range then test just that; display a message or highlight the invalid cells; list the invalid cells in a form allowing the user to edit and replace them?

Comment: 1st or 3rd suggestions is what I am looking for. I wish for the user to be made aware if data he has pasted has broken data validation rules. This can be through error/warning message or highlighting of invalid cells, whichever is possible.

Comment: You will have to attempt it then and come back when you encounter something that you can't solve. SO isn't a code writing service. I'll help you in the right direction but only so far.

Comment: I have created a code to check for invalid cells. I am now having trouble searching a range to produce a msgbox if an invalid cell is found as detailed in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided not to go down the shape route and instead search for validation values:

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("D4:H8")
    If Not Cell.Validation.Value Then
        MsgBox "Actions Should Have Input and Output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a paste special; a normal paste overwrites the format property of the cells.

Comment: The idea is for someone with no knowledge of VBA or data validation to copy and paste as they wish, but be informed that they are breaking a rule.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of clicking the cell and hitting paste, click the cell and paste the data into the formula bar at the top of excel. Then hit enter. This allowed me to paste text from the clipboard but retain the data validation.

I only tested this with text and numbers within excel and from external sources, never with advanced formulas, etc, so it may not work for all needs.

It is one extra step per paste, but it saved me lots of time on a specific project where I needed to check character counts.