# How Data Validation work in Excel when copy/paste data from different source

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have 5 different columns in my excel sheet and each having separate data validation rules. My rules are working when user manually enters through keyboard.
But, while copy pasting data from different source like `notepad`, `one note` etc. my validation doesn't work. Only it works when you click on the `cell` individually.
Example: My columns are like, 
`Name, Employee ID, Plan ID, Client Name, Email ID` etc

I need some kind of `VBA` or formula where my data validation automatically works when user copy/paste data from different source.

Comment: See here for an example where a message is displayed if rules are going to be overwritten https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386971/force-pasted-values-to-obey-data-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have met the same problem. I have solved it by blocking pasting at all. In the module I have a code:

```
Sub NotAllowPaste()
Dim UndoList As String
If ThisWorkbook.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub
With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  UndoList = .CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
  If InStr(UndoList, "Paste") > 0 Or _
    UndoList = "Keep Source Formatting" Or _
    UndoList = "Drag and Drop" Then
        .Undo
        MsgBox "Pasting and ""drag and drop"" is forbidden in this workbook.", vbCritical
  End If
  .EnableEvents = True  
End With
End Sub
```

Then, in the worksheet code I have put:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  NotAllowPaste
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
  Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End Sub
```

As you can see, I have disabled formula bar also to prevent user copying directly into it. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Correct me if i have missed anything. You guys have provided me the solution to prevent the copy/paste. But, my requirement is to allow user to paste in my validated sheet from different source. User cann't create the records manually every time. Assume if we have 1000+ records extracted from data base or from external flat files. User wants to paste these 1000 records in my sheet and wants to validate. Please provide any solution for this.

Comment: It depends, what kind of validation do you need. Shall data be in any list, or be numeric and in some scope, or begin with upper case,  or whatever.

Comment: As i have mentioned earlier, i have 5 different columns in my spreadsheet. Eg. NAME column - It has 3 validations runs through VBA and list. Like, maximum 40 characters long, special characters not allowed and required field in case of first record entry. EMAIL has their own email validation runs through list. EMP ID has 7 digit numeric only validation through list. So, different column has different validation in my first sheet1. I want to get all validated once the user tries to paste some junk data in my sheet1 from different source.

Answer (score 0):

the subroutine checking against the list, in the normal module:

```
Sub ListToCheck(rng As Range)
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim bMatch As Boolean
Dim sListName As String

sListName = "sheet2!MyList" 'change this accrording to your needs
bMatch = False

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    With WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To .CountA(Range("MyList"))
        If cl.Value = .Index(Range(sListName), i) Then bMatch = True
    Next i
    End With

    With cl.Interior
    If bMatch Then
        .ColorIndex = 0
    Else
        .Color = vbYellow
    End If
    End With
    bMatch = False
Next cl

End Sub
```

and another one for checking, if value inserted between two longs:

```
Sub ValueToCheck(rng As Range, minV As Long, maxV As Long)
Dim cl As Range
Dim bOk As Boolean

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    With cl
    If IsNumeric(.Value) Then

        If .Value < minV Or .Value > maxV Then
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow
         Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Else
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
    End With
Next cl
End Sub
```

Then, one small macro in the sheet when validation should be used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim col As Range
Dim colAdr As String

For Each col In Target.Columns
    colAdr = col.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    Select Case Right(colAdr, Len(colAdr) - InStrRev(colAdr, "C"))
        Case Is = 1
            ListToCheck col
        Case Is = 2
            ValueToCheck col, 1000000, 9999999
        End Select
Next col
End Sub
```

I have assumed that the first column is to be check against some list, and the second shall be between 1000000 and 9999999. But you can modify it accordingly. As you can see, I do not use excel validation - this can be inadvertently overwritten by the user when pasting. I have made macros to fill non valid cell with yellow, but you can order it doing something else. I wouldn't recommend msgbox if you think that somebody may try to paste 1 000 or more values.